# apostrophecms beforeSave won't work

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This is my schema and construct method for **automatically update title**. But it won’t work at all ! It kept prompt me to fill in **Full Name** . You may fork my github to see the whole code [My Github Apostrophe Tutorial](https://github.com/ammein/test-apostrophe) . Someone pleaseeee help me. I falled in love with apostrophe badly. The tutorial that I have been followed is [Setting the Title Automatically](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#customizing-the-model-layer-setting-the-code-title-code-automatically)

```js
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    permissionsFields : true,
    name: 'person',
    label: 'Person',
    pluralLabel: 'People',
    beforeConstruct : function(self,options){
        options.addFields= 
        [
            {
                name: 'title',
                label: 'Full Name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            {
                name: 'firstName',
                label: 'First Name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            {
                name: 'lastName',
                label: 'Last Name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            {
                name: 'body',
                label: 'Biography',
                type: 'area',
                options: {
                    widgets: {
                        'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                            toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
                        },
                        'apostrophe-images': {}
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'phone',
                label: 'Phone',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'thumbnail',
                label: 'Thumbnail',
                type: 'singleton',
                widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
                options: {
                    limit: 1,
                    minSize: [200, 200],
                    aspectRatio: [1, 1]
                }
            }
        ].concat(options.addFields || [])
    },
    arrangeFields: [{
            name: 'contact',
            label: 'Contact',
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phone']
        },
        {
            name: 'admin',
            label: 'Administrative',
            fields: ['slug', 'published', 'tags']
        },
        {
            name: 'content',
            label: 'Biographical',
            fields: ['thumbnail', 'body']
        }
    ],
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
            piece.title = piece.firstName + ' ' + piece.lastName;
            return callback();
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Stuart Romanek , Now I know that the required field will prompt user to fill in. I can override it by using **contextual** just like you said. The problem is , the **slug**. But I figured that I have to put **contextual** too.

```js
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    permissionsFields : true,
    name: 'person',
    label: 'Person',
    pluralLabel: 'People',
    beforeConstruct : function(self,options){
        options.addFields= 
        [
            {
                name: 'firstName',
                label: 'First Name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'lastName',
                label: 'Last Name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true
            },
            {
                name: 'title',
                label: 'Full Name',
                type: 'string',
                required: true,
                contextual : true
            },
            {
                name: 'slug',
                label: 'Slug',
                type: 'string',
                required: true,
                contextual: true
            },
            {
                name: 'body',
                label: 'Biography',
                type: 'area',
                options: {
                    widgets: {
                        'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                            toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
                        },
                        'apostrophe-images': {}
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'phone',
                label: 'Phone',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'thumbnail',
                label: 'Thumbnail',
                type: 'singleton',
                widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
                options: {
                    limit: 1,
                    minSize: [200, 200],
                    aspectRatio: [1, 1]
                }
            }
        ].concat(options.addFields || [])
    },
    arrangeFields: [{
            name: 'contact',
            label: 'Contact',
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phone']
        },
        {
            name: 'admin',
            label: 'Administrative',
            fields: ['slug', 'published', 'tags']
        },
        {
            name: 'content',
            label: 'Biographical',
            fields: ['thumbnail', 'body']
        }
    ],
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
            // Override title and MUST SET CONTEXTUAL to able to save. Let the 
            // backend self.beforeSave method do this thing.
            // You know why I don't set piece.slug ?
            // Because once you already set title , apostrophe made it for you :)
            // BUT must put contextual : true on slug. If not, it will prompt you :*
            piece.title = piece.firstName + ' ' + piece.lastName;
            return callback();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`beforeSave` is going to happen on the server after the user submits the piece, so the browser-side `required` validation is going to stop the submission before it gets a chance to construct the `title` property.

You can omit the `required` property on the `title` field and your `beforeSave` will work as expected. If you want to force the title be set programmatically and not include the field in the form, you can set `contextual: true` on the `title` field and the field won't be rendered in the manager.